# Pages in WordPress do not open in the same window when i click any link thar open new tab

Tags: wordpress

Pages in WordPress do not open in the same window when i click any link thar open new tab

Comment: we will surely help you if you can post the code that is generating such type of links

Answer (score 0):

remove this excerpt from your links in html or php, however you coded them.

From

```
<a href="/" target="_blank">Home</a>
```

To

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by the user's browser preferences. No way to "force" it to happen on any client's machine.